# lucene solr - how do i skip words in query which are absent in the solr database

Tags: solr, lucene

for examle i have such records in my solr:

```
name:1 doctor teacher worker
name:2 cat dog mouse
name:3 table chair sofa
```

i do this query to solr:

```
/q=name:(teacher AND doctor)
```

it returns me all records which have "teacher", "doctor" in its name field (1-st record).

if i make this query:

```
/q=name:(teacher AND doctor AND dog)
```

it returns nothing because i have no words "dog", "teacher", "doctor" together in the name field.

if i make this query:

```
/q=name:(teacher AND doctor AND bird)
```

it returns nothing because i have no words "bird", "teacher", "doctor" together in the name field.

my problem is that i need to remove from search query all words which are not present in solr database at all.

so i need that the query:

```
/q=name:(teacher AND doctor AND bird)
```

returns the same results as:

```
/q=name:(teacher AND doctor)
```

because word "bird" does not exist in the database at all

and query:

```
/q=name:(teacher AND doctor AND dog)
```

returns nothing because word "dog" exists in the "2 cat dog mouse" record.

how can i do that?

any help appriciated!

Comment: it's really a bad use case, and a wrong usage of inverted index data structure

Comment: cant understand what you mean..

Comment: I mean, Solr is not a database, and it's not a good use case to think about it as a DB, also use case about removing terms, that are absent sounds to me very dubious